# Decrementing and incrementing value in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, increment, decrement

I am trying to calculate discount on the fly using the following jquery code.

```
$(document).on("change keyup blur", "#chDiscount", function(){ 
        var amd=$('#cBalance').val();
        var disc = $('#chDiscount').val();
        if(isNaN(disc)){
            disc = 0;
        }
         $('#cBalance').val(amd-disc);             

      });
```

To escape non-numeric key:

```
    var specialKeys = new Array();
    specialKeys.push(8,46); //Backspace
  function IsNumeric(e) {
    var keyCode = e.which ? e.which : e.keyCode;
    console.log( keyCode );
    var ret = ((keyCode >= 48 && keyCode <= 57) || specialKeys.indexOf(keyCode) != -1);
    return ret;
  }
```

The problem is When I type in chDiscount input, the new value of cBalance is fine but When I erase the chDiscount value, I could no longer get the old(default) value of the cBalance input. I want the old value if I delete the Discount value. How can I do that? Please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

are you using jquery? I'm fan with jquery so I'll have my suggestion base on jquery. You can get ideas with this I hope.

What about store the initial value first using in the element jquery has that example.

```
$('#cBalance').data({origValue: 999});
```

Try this simple fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/jeorlie/b71epf02/

try using 10 as input in balance and deduct it with 3(assuming 3 was the total discount). You would get 7 in the balance. If you remove the discount (make it 0) you will have the original value.

This code in fiddle is buggy but you can get ideas with it, just analyze it. By the way. You can you store original value of Balance into a variable which is globally accessible. Hope you get ideas with it.

Comment: This really helps.